# Laravel : Eloquent Form

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have users and they have xp. I order all my users like this :

```
User::orderBy('xp', 'desc')->get();
```

But now I want to get one user rank. So I want to order my user list by xp and get the position of one specific user in this list.

Is this possible without a foreach ?

Thanks

Comment: Show the Table structure for User table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its really just two queries:

```
$user = User::find($id)

$position = User::where('x', '>=', $user->xp)->count();
```

So first just get the user in question, then run a query to see how many `users` have more `XP` than this `user`.

Comment: Oh ! Pretty smart ! Didn't think like that ! Thanks :)

Comment: Keep in mind that this will create an additional query to DB for every user.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I want to use it in the show of one user so It will not make query for every user, no ?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin It will create a count query. You're solution involves hydrating every model which is much more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Since you get a collection, you can do this:

```
$users = User::orderBy('xp', 'desc')->get();

$position = $users->where('name', 'John')->keys()->first() + 1; // Get position by name.
$position = $users->where('id', 5)->keys()->first() + 1; // Get position by user ID.
```

This solution will not create any additional query to DB.

Comment: `User::orderBy('xp', 'desc')->get();` will result in getting and hydrating every user in the table.

Comment: @AlexHarris if all OP needs is displaying a position just for one user per request, he should use your solution. In case if he wants to display position for a bunch of loaded users, this solution will be better. I assumed he wants to show positions for a bunch of users since he had shown `get()` query and mentioned foreach.